# ASCII or binary protocol

Tags: ios, bluetooth, binary, ascii, protocols

I have a breath analyzer that generates 30 to 50 numbers for each breath of a subject.
Each value has its own name, UM, decimal places and range.
I need to define a protocol (command/response/data) that allows a iphone 6 to connect the analyzer via Bluetooth (RFCOMM),
start a test and collect the data breath-by-breath.
The expected maximum data rate is one breath per second.
My first idea was to create a ASCII protocol strongly inspired to NMEA standard

$CMD,value1,value2,....,ValueN*CS

A typical breath could be something like this:

$PD21,38,138,0,3,176,75,738,2092,5,,630,,717,86,41,231,90,150,100,151,-8,3391484,,,86,30,18,1,1070,257,766,617,115,283,234,36,42,590,278,128,185,5200,22,5431,25,5599,26,4664,19,70,428,711,3231,2625,81,1546,466,93,36,670,730,1194,1662,2571,775,1407,573*0e00

A colleague of mine is telling that such a solution would consume a lot of CPU resource due to the parsing job.
He says that human readability does not add any value to our application and then a binary protocol would be much more convenient.
My idea is that a textual protocol allows simplified debugging and testability, is self-explanatory and extensible.
But I've no idea how the impact on a iphone 6 could be.
Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: the phone is powerful, what about the analyser, what's best for it to deal with... also, the smaller the size the better when using BTLE

Comment: It is a trivial amount of data, so processing power won't be an issue. However, I would suggest that you adopt a BLE GATT attribute for the sensor reading rather than using GATT to emirate a serial port. You can use notify to provide the sensor readings. And yes, using binary data will make more efficient use of the BLE bandwidth

Comment: BLE is not an option. Everything will work with Bluetooth classic. The breath analyser will work as an External Accessory and will exploit the EA framework.